# Hash ordering preserved between iterations if not modified?

Tags: ruby, hash

If I iterate over a hash once, then do so again without modifying the contents, are the keys guaranteed to appear in the same order?

A quick test suggests as much:

```
> h = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3}
> 100_000.times.map { h.to_s == h.to_s }.all?
=> true
```

Another question, if the above is allowed, can I iterate through it changing only values, without adding any new keys, and have the ordering of the keys be unchanged?

similar to this python question: [Do dicts preserve iteration order if they are not modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849324/do-python-dicts-preserve-iteration-order-if-they-are-not-modified)

Unlike the proposed duplicate I'm not interested in whether the elements have a fully specified order, only the restriction that two consecutive iterations without modification provide the same sequence.

Comment: As both answers state, insertion order is maintained. This confuses people who think "ordered" means "sorted", which they're not unless we're allowing for an invisible time stamp inside the Hash class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: What is the order of keys/values returned by Hash.keys and Hash.values methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208512/ruby-what-is-the-order-of-keys-values-returned-by-hash-keys-and-hash-values-met)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Prior to 1.9, behavior of enumerated hashes was not in the ruby specification and therefore was up to implementation -- basically, hash enumeration behavior/pattern was undefined by the language and implementations could really do whatever they want (random? sorted? insertion order? different method every time? anything goes!)

1.9+, hash enumeration is specified by the language to be in the order of insertion, so if you know your platform is 1.9+, you can rely on it.

[**RubySpec**](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/hash/keys_spec.rb)

Comment: ruby 2.2.0+ doesn't follow rubyspec anymore, see http://rubini.us/2014/12/31/matz-s-ruby-developers-don-t-use-rubyspec/

Comment: And rubyspec spawned back to life after more than a thousand commits http://eregon.github.io/rubyspec/2015/07/29/rubyspec-is-reborn.html