# How do I add a key/value pair to the beginning of a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

My code is:

```
hash = { two: 2, three: 3 }

def hash_add(hash, new_key, new_value)
  temp_hash = {}

  temp_hash[new_key.to_sym] = new_value
  temp_hash.merge!(hash)
  hash = temp_hash
  puts hash

end

hash_add(hash, 'one', 1)
```

Within the method, `puts hash` returns `{ :one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3 }`, but when `hash1` is put to the method, it remains unchanged afterward.  It's like the assignment isn't carrying itself outside of the function.

I guess I could return the updated hash and set the hash I want to change to it outside the method:

```
hash = hash_add(hash, 'one', 1)
```

But I just don't see why the assignment I give to the hash does not stick outside of the method.

I have this, which works:

```
def hash_add(hash, new_key, new_value)
  temp_hash = {}

  temp_hash[new_key.to_sym] = new_value
  temp_hash.merge!(hash)
  hash.clear

  temp_hash.each do |key, value|
    hash[key] = value
  end
end
```

Which gives me what I'm wanting when this method is called, but it just seems a little excessive to have to rebuild the hash like that.

Comment: you have to understand that in most dynamic languages, variables are nothing but references. the first solution creates a local reference (rebinds a variable) to the hash, it doesn't update the original reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby passes objects to methods by value, but the value is the reference to the object, so when you set `hash=temp_hash` within the `add_hash` method, that change only applies inside the method.  The value of hash outside the method is unchanged.

```
def hash_add(hash, new_key, new_value)
  temp_hash = {}

  temp_hash[new_key.to_sym] = new_value
  temp_hash.merge!(hash)
  hash = temp_hash
  hash
end
h2 = hash_add(hash, 'one', 1)
hash
=> {:two=>2, :three=>3}
h2
=>{:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
```

If you want hash to be updated, you need to replace the contents of hash rather than re-point hash at a new object as you did with the clear and re-adding the values.  You can also do it with the `replace` method.

```
def hash_add(hash, new_key, new_value)
  temp_hash = {}

  temp_hash[new_key.to_sym] = new_value
  temp_hash.merge!(hash)
  hash.replace temp_hash
end
```

There are some good diagrams about pass by value in "[Is Ruby pass by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value)"

Comment: if it is always passed by value then how come the array is updated in this case. `a = [1,2,3]

def meth(a,v)
  a << v
end;

meth(a,34)  #=> a is now [1, 2, 3, 34]`

Comment: Because you are mutating the array. When you change the array, the array changes (duh). That's just how shared mutable state works.

Answer (score 18):

How about this?

```
hash1 = { two: 2, three: 3 }

#add a new key,value 
hash1 = Hash[:one,1].merge!(hash1) #=> {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
```

Example #2:

```
h = { two: 2, three: 3 }

def hash_add(h,k,v)
  Hash[k.to_sym,v].merge!(h)
end

h = hash_add(h, 'one', 1) #=> {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}
```

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE: this answer is old from times when Ruby 1.8 was still around.**

In general, the class `Hash` in Ruby does not provide ordering. Behavior might differ between Ruby versions / implementations.

See also: [Hash ordering preserved between iterations if not modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355316/ruby-hash-ordering-preserved)

If you want ordering, you need to use the class `OrderedHash` which is provided through ActiveSupport

See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash

Comment: only true for ruby < 1.9

Comment: I'm using numbers here just for simplicity's sake.  What I want to do is add a key value pair to the beginning of a hash.

Comment: @kylewilliamshike yes, as I said: it differs between Ruby versions / implementations -- probably not something which should be assumed one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the function you are just `puts`ing the hash, not returning it. Perhaps if you changed `puts hash` to `return hash` it would work (I haven't tried it myself).

Answer (score 0):

`temp_hash` is a local variable, which gets deleted once the function returns.

Comment: But if the data that was attached to it is reassigned to a variable that isn't local, like hash1, shouldn't it stick around?