# Ruby each multi array

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
web_user_agents = {
    "linux" => [
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008122903 Gentoo Iceweasel/3.0.5",
            "Opera/5.0 (Linux 2.0.38 i386; U) [en]",
    ],
    "windows" => [
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2a1pre) Gecko",
            "Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.2; U; en) Presto/2.1.1",
    ],
}
```

How can I iterate every element with key?

The output expected is:

```
"linux","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008122903 Gentoo Iceweasel/3.0.5"
"linux","Opera/5.0 (Linux 2.0.38 i386; U) [en]"
"windows","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2a1pre) Gecko"
"windows","Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.2; U; en) Presto/2.1.1",
```

Comment: Your question is hard to decipher. Show us expected output, the code you've already written to try to generate that output, and the actual output. In the meantime, look up the documentation on the Ruby `keys` method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-keys

Comment: The output expected are 4 rows:

"linux","Mozilla/5.0..."
"linux","Opera/5.0..."
"windows","Mozilla/5..."
"windows","Opera/9.63...",

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a hash in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227571/how-to-iterate-over-a-hash-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the hash

```
web_user_agents.map { |k,v| v.map { |val| [k, val] } }.flatten

#=>[
#=> "linux","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008122903 Gentoo Iceweasel/3.0.5"
#=> "linux","Opera/5.0 (Linux 2.0.38 i386; U) [en]"
#=> "windows","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2a1pre) Gecko"
#=> "windows","Opera/9.63 (Windows NT 5.2; U; en) Presto/2.1.1"
#=>]
```

Comment: +1 for one liner. I was thinking the same thing only down this way. `web_user_agents.map{|k,v| [k].cycle(v.count).zip(v)}.flatten(1)` so he would have an array of the key value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't really want the terminating comma on your last row, try:

```
web_user_agents.keys.each do |agent|
    web_user_agents[agent].each do |line|
        puts %Q("#{agent}","#{line}")
    end
end
```

<strike>Be aware that hashes are stored in non-deterministic order; if it matters to you how the keys come out, you may want to order them, or use an array instead of a hash to store them.</strike>

[EDIT: In recent versions of Ruby, hash key order is preserved.]

Comment: Actually hashes were stored in non-deterministic order only for ruby versions prior to 1.9.2, from then on, the insertion order is preserved. https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/hash/keys_spec.rb and http://stackoverflow.com/a/17355411/687142

Comment: Man, you turn your back for one second! Thanks for the info, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The comma in the last row is permitted, but has no effect.  Some add the comma in case they later decide to add other elements.

Answer (score 0):

The following loops over the main hash.

```
 web_user_agents.each_pair do |k,v| 
   puts "#{k} => #{v}"
 end
```

You can nest this like so:

```
 web_user_agents.each_pair do |k,v|
   v.each do |value|
      puts "#{k} => #{value}"
   end
 end
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output.

Comment: I think the OP is able to format the output on her/his own!

Comment: Would you say that if the OP were your project lead and you had been asked to format the output in a particular way?  Why do it differently when it's just as easy to do it as requested?